# Differentiating the Taylor expansion of $e^x$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

It is well known that a) $\frac{d}{dx}\exp x = \exp x$ and b) $\exp x = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} + ...$. Therefore, it should be possible to differentiate this Taylor series representation of $\exp$ and get back the same function. Doing this:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\exp x = \frac{d}{dx}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{nx^{n-1}}{n!} = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}$$

This is fairly unsurprising, however this has a problem - consider the differentiated series at $n=0$. This term simplifies (trivially) to "$\frac{1}{x(-1)!}$". $(-1)!$ is now involved with this. There seems be no obvious reason to change the starting index to 1 either.

Comment: The $n=0$ term is a constant. Its derivative is $0$.

Comment: But when represented as $x^0$, it gives the term regardless. Clearly it is negligable... but yes, I guess that's correct.

Comment: To elaborate on David's comment, keep in mind that $(x^0)'$ and $\int x^{-1}dx$ are not related and you have to take care of them.

Comment: You cannot cancel $0$ from $0!$ to get $(-1)!$, because it is not defined that way.

Comment: After differentiating, the sum begins at index $n=1$ because the first term vanishes. Then you can reindex to get exactly the original sum.

Comment: Ohh... ridiculous computational mistakes as usual. Thank you.

Comment: Also, remember that $\Gamma (s) = (s-1)!$ so you need $s \to 0$ not $s\to -1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the case where $n=0$, you cannot cancel $n$ on the top and bottom because $0!=1$ has no factor of $0$. I suggest making the $n=0$ case separate.

$$\exp{x}=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

Then after deriving, just shift your index.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is, basically, that you differentiated all factors $\frac{x^n}{n!}$ and got $\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}$, when in fact, this is only true for $n>0$. For $n=0$, this is not true:

$$0=\left(\frac{x^0}{0!}\right)' \neq \frac{x^{-1}}{(-1)!}$$